# Google Analytics (gtag.js): Product List Name doesn't appear but other fields do

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm implementing GA Enhanced E-commerce using the new `gtag.js` library. I want to send information about product impressions and product clicks, following the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce.

Everything works (I can see the data in GA), **except for Product List Name**.

The docs seem to be inconsistent in naming the property (sometimes it's called `"list"` and sometimes `"list_name"`) and none of them worked for me.

Here's my (simplified) code:

```js
deals = [           
  {
    "id": "18",
    "name": "Some product",
    "list": "All Deals", // also tried "list_name" here
    "category": "Multiplatform",
    "list_position": "1",
    "price": "18,39",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "product_url": "https://www.amazon.com/someproduct",
  },
  ...
]

...

// on page load
gtag('event', 'view_item_list', {
  "items": deals
});

...

// on click
gtag('event', 'select_content', {
  "content_type": "product",
  "items": [
    deals[0]
  ]
});
```

All the data successfully make their way to GA, but Product List Name shows `(not set)`, no matter what:

[image]

Thanks for any idea on how to fix/debug this!

Answer (score 0):

there is an error/mistake/inconsistency in `gtag` documentation:

- you should use `list_name` instead of `list`

it works as expected with `list_name`

---

**!!! DO NOT USE** `gtag` as it *does not send* `list_name` value with events such as `select_content` and `view_item`

in short, query parameter `pal` (Product Action List) for `collect` call via `gtag` is not included, when using `gtag` — this is a major error comparing to `analytics.js` implementation.

Comment: So you're saying the solution is to go back to the old analytics.js and stop using gtag.js until Google fixes it, correct?

Comment: @LukasKovarik correct, current solution is to stick with `analytics.js` implementation

Comment: As of January 2020, gtag seems to send it.

Answer (score 0):

You can send 2 events, when adding to cart from any list:

```
gtag('event','view_item',deals); gtag('event','add_to_cart',deals);
```

name of list must be set in list_name.

```
deals = [{"id": "18","name": "Some product","list_name": "All Deals", ...}]
```

Then it works fine.