# Gtag list_name property not working as described in documentation

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

In the documentation for gtag, there are properties named "list_name" and "list_position" available for products. However, when passing these properties into gtag as described at:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce

No list data is sent via the request to /collect. As a result, after switching to gtag, our "Product List Performance" tab in analytics is not showing any meaningful product data. It shows all of our list names, as these are provided by the Impression's "il1nm" parameter. However, "Product List Clicks", "Product Adds To Cart", etc, are all empty.

I've identified that the "pal" parameter is simply not being set on the request to /collect. Even if I straight up copy/paste the example in the docs, the request still does not provide that parameter.

Is this a bug? It is simply unacceptable that this does not work properly, especially with gtag being the recommended integration.

Answer (score 0):

`list` and `list_name` **does NOT work** with `gtag` implementation.

It is a GA bug:

[Google Analytics (gtag.js): Product List Name doesn't appear but other fields do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892020/google-analytics-gtag-js-product-list-name-doesnt-appear-but-other-fields-do)

Comment: I thought this would be the answer, but was hoping for more information. At the moment, I've written code that manually pings Google's measurement protocol for these events.